# Forcing a:visited link color for both hash and main link in CSS?

Tags: html, css, hash

From what I noticed, hash links are considered separate from the main link (ie. without hash) in CSS?

For example, when I have CSS:

```
a:link{color:blue}
a:visited{color:red}
```

and have two links:

```
http://example.com/page/
http://example.com/page/#msg15
```

Now when I click on the second (the one with #msg15) link ONLY then the first link will not be marked as visited (in red color)?

Why is it so?

My question is - is it possible to do it with CSS that when I visit the hashed link only then the main link (without hash) is also automatically considered as visited?

Comment: No. According to the browser, these are two different pages. Moreover, they could just as easily be two different pages to the server.

Comment: Hm, I thought it'd be possible to 'force' it somehow (yes, I understand these could be different pages for tab content etc..)